# Determine the values of $a$ and $b$ so that $Var(Q)$ is at minimum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance

I've got this question that says both $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and $\mu \ne 0$, the correlation is $p, -1<p<1$

We have $$Q=aX+bY$$ and it is unbiased estimator of $\mu$.
we want to determine the values of $a$ and $b$ so that $Var(Q)$ is minimised.

---

I'll show what I did, which doesn't feel right near the end,
$E(Q)=\mu$ , since $Q$ is unbiased.
$Var(Q)=Var(aX+bY)$
$Var(Q)=a^2Var(X)+b^2Var(Y)+2abCov(X,Y)$
$Var(Q)=a^2\sigma^2+b^2\sigma^2+2abCov(X,Y)$

$Cov(X,Y)=Corr(X,Y)\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}$, which gives us $Cov(X,Y)=p\sigma^2$

now $Var(Q)=a^2\sigma^2+b^2\sigma^2+2ab\sigma^2p$

I think to get $Var(Q)$ at minimum, the first derivative needs to equal to zero, which doesn't feel right for me for some reason.
$d\over dp$ $(a^2\sigma^2+b^2\sigma^2+2ab\sigma^2p)$
$=2ab\sigma^2=0$, which gives me either $a$ or $b$ or $\sigma=0$

to confirm my findings, the second derivative needs to be larger than zero, which doesn't work in this case.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: Use $E(Q)=\mu$ to see that $b=1-a$ and then differentiate $Var(Q)$ with respect to $a$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot that $a$ and $b$ are functionally connected by a relation that $Q$ is unbiased esimator: 
$$
\mathbb E[Q] = a\mathbb E[X]+b\mathbb E[Y]=(a+b)\mu = \mu.
$$
so $a+b=1$ or $b=1-a$.

Therefore 
$$
\text{Var}(Q)=a^2\sigma^2+(1-a)^2\sigma^2+2a(1-a)\sigma^2p.
$$

Equate first derivative to zero and get $a=\frac12$, what could be predicted in advance by virtue of symmetry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I haven't thought of calculating $E(Q)$ in steps and jumped prematurely to the end.